# log of nimbus read another vesion of zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm new to storm .. i imported project using `storm-0.8.2`  and  installed `zookeeper-3.4.7` with `storm -0.8.2`

I ran nimbus `bin/storm nimbus` and  found in the log of the nimbus another version for `zookeeper`

```
[INFO] Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3-1073969,built on 02/23/2011 22:27 GMT
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: It there any problem due to different version? If not, why changing it? Why not installing ZK 3.3.3 instead of 3.4.7?

Comment: i tried to install -3.3.3 but it has issues with connection . so i tried to install stable version but this error appeared

Comment: The show message is an `INFO` message an no error. After starting the cluster can you submit topology? Or is there any problem?

Comment: no actually it worked well but i asked for why it read different version !

Comment: It only shows the client version that is shipped with Storm (ie, the ZK client version that is included in Storm binaries). Ie, Storm does not use the binaries from your ZK installation to connect to ZK. As long as the APIs are compatible, there is no reason to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown message is an `INFO` message an no error. It only shows the client version that is shipped with Storm (ie, the ZK client version that is included in Storm binaries). Ie, Storm does not use the binaries from your ZK installation to connect to ZK. As long as the APIs are compatible, there is no reason to worry about it.

The only way to "resolve" this would be to use a different Storm version (that ships with a different ZK version or to install a different ZK (ie, `3.3.3` instead of `3.4.7`)